# What is a "boarding shoulder" and how does it relate to ferry check-in closing?

Tags: ferries

On the website of [superfast ferries](https://www.superfast.com/en-gb/check-in-boarding) on check-in and boarding is written:

> Boarding Shoulder:
>
> Passengers & Vehicles:
> **2 hours before departure**

Further down on the page, it says in small letters:

> Check-in Closing time: 30' before departure

I would read a check-in closing time 30 minutes before departure such that if I arrive 45 minutes before departure, I can check in and board the vessel.  Is this interpretation correct or wrong?  What does the "boarding shoulder" mean?  In my experience, 2 hours is more typical for international overnight ferries than 30 minutes.  The page also notes that *all passengers are kindly required to proceed to the embarkation area, at least 3 hours prior to the scheduled departure time*.  Would I still be allowed to enter if my train is delayed and I arrive 2½ or 1½ hour before departure as a foot passenger?

Comment: In transport jargon, a 'shoulder' can be a period just before or after a peak of activity (think of a graph of activity or traffic). In rail transit there are 'shoulders' before and after the morning and evening weekday peaks, at least there were before Covid and working from home.

Comment: Maybe I should queue 2 hours before to be sure to reach check-in 30 minutes before departure?

Answer (score 6):

That is one screwed up web page. If I look at the **Italian** language page and translate it to English, at least the Patras destination makes sense:

[image]

("Low Season/Mid Season Boarding" here corresponds to "Shoulder Boarding")

Maybe you should enquire directly with the ferry company as the the actual recommended arrival time for  your situation (and get it in writing).

Comment: For the confused, "shoulder season" is a term meaning "the parts of the year between peak tourist season and minimum tourist season".  It wouldn't surprise me if the translator somehow had heard of that term but got the idiom wrong.

Comment: (And now I see that @MichaelHarvey pointed out the same usage in the comments on the question)

Comment: "Maybe you should enquire directly with the ferry company as the the actual recommended arrival time for your situation (and get it in writing)." => could we do it on behalf of OP?